# Share data between bash and php

Tags: linux, php, bash

We are trying to create a project that will run on linux. But we want to see results from browser. We want to use PHP for that but we are not really sure how to share data between those two environment. We dont want to use MySql or any other dbms for that not to use ram just for 1 or 2 data.

So the question is; "We want to share 1 or at most 2 data between bash and PHP. How can we do this without third party application or server ?"

Thanks for answers
Baris

Comment: Actually the question is not about PHP but Bash that is why I wrote it here. The problem is, when I try to write result to a file, I may sometimes need to open and write  Nx100 times to that file. Which creates a peformance problem with harddisks. So I am looking for a solution that directly uses Ram and shares data between bash and PHP through RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a bash script and you want to run that from PHP and handle the output in some way. PHP has [several functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) to accomodate that.

The backtick operator example in the PHP docs is:

```
<?php
$output = `ls -al`;
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you're trying to do...but one possible solution would be to write your data to a file or two.  Either PHP or your cli environment can read/write the file to get/set the data.  Note that if both environments expect to write the data you would need to implement some sort of locking mechanism.

You could also use something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/), which would provide you with a memory-based key/value store without the "overhead" of a complete RDBMS solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a Stack Exchange question, but PHP runs fine in CLI mode and can do whatever bash would do, without much extra effort.  So I would use PHP for the background or CLI process (optionally calling a bash shell script as needed if you want to use PHP as a wrapper only) then use PHP also for the web part.  The two parts can share PHP code if required, particularly the part that reads/writes from a shared file.

Locking of this file will be the main challenge as mentioned - creating a lock directory with mkdir (since it's atomic) would be one way, but you'd also need to ensure locks can be cleaned up.

UPDATE: this approach would also work if you want to write to shared RAM instead of a file - you could use memcached or similar from PHP, but there is no way to do that from bash.

Comment: Actually the question is not about PHP but Bash that is why I wrote it here. The problem is, when I try to write result to a file, I may sometimes need to open and write Nx100 times to that file. Which creates a peformance problem with harddisks. So I am looking for a solution that directly uses Ram and shares data between bash and PHP through RAM.

Comment: You already have some PHP in this solution: the more you write in PHP the more you can do, as PHP is a real programming language with libraries - e.g. you could use memcached as suggested.  You haven't said how many writes you need to do per second, or how large they are.  Really this should be on Stack Exchange anyway.